# Boolean Algebra expression simplification with mulitple theoerms

Tags: boolean-expression

How does this does this Boolean expression simplify? I have used theorem 8, 7 and distribution.
However, I am coming up short on this and it becomes massively long and complex, which strikes me as wrong.  Please can anyone help

(A+!C+!D)(!B+!C+D)(A+!B+!C)

I'm pully my hair out on this

Comment: This would like be better off on the computer science exchange.

Comment: Thank you sorry, I was just trying to get to an explanation.  I'll remember next time

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea if this is the most simplified one. I get this:

```
(A + !C + !D)*(!B + !C + D)*(A + !B + !C)
  |
  | 
  V
(A*!B + A*!C + A*D + !B*!C + !C + !C*D + !B*!D + !C*!D)*(A + !B + !C)
  |
  | Absorption Law applied to '!C'
  V
(A*!B + A*D + !C + !B*!D)*(A + !B + !C)
  |
  |
  V
A*!B + A*!B + A*!B*!C + A*D + A*!B*D + A*!C*D + A*!C + !B*!C + !C + A*!B*!D + !B*!D + !B*!C*!D
  |
  | Absorption Law applied to '!C1', 'A*!B', and '!B*!D'
  V
A*!B + A*D + !C + !B*!D
```

Comment: There are Boolean expression simplifiers out there that give the answer, yours is really close.  But more importantly I see how you were going about it, which is really what I'm after, thank you

Comment: @ConnorMeek What's the name of that tool (or website)? I'm curious about what the simplest form we can get, too.